# Can't work out MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table which has the following data.

```
surveyid | staff  | username | ipaddress | rating  | comments 
---------|--------|----------|-----------|---------|----------
0        | staff1 | user1    | 1.1.1.1   | 10      | none
1        | staff2 | user2    | 1.2.1.1   | 5       | none
2        | staff2 | user3    | 1.2.1.1   | 10      | none
3        | staff2 | user2    | 1.2.1.1   | 6       | none
4        | staff3 | user4    | 1.1.1.51  | 10      | none
5        | staff4 | user3    | 1.21.12.1 | 9       | none
6        | staff5 | user2    | 1.12.1.1  | 10      | none
```

I am wanting a query that will select surveyid, staff, username and ipaddress only when an ipaddress has been used for multiple users for the same staff.

Basicly I am wanting to find out what staff has multiple users submit off the same ip address.

I have tried the following but it does not work.

```
SELECT * FROM `comment_data` CD 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT `ipaddress`, COUNT(DISTINCT `staff`)
FROM `comment_data` GROUP BY `ipaddress` HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `staff`) > 1 )
USECOUNT ON USECOUNT.`ipaddress` = CD.`ipaddress`
```

I also tried the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM `commend_data` WHERE `staff`+`ipaddress` IN
(SELECT `staff`+`ipaddress` FROM `comment_data` GROUP BY `staff`, `ipaddress`
HAVING COUNT(`surveyid`) > 1)
```

Also I want to make sure I display all duplicates and I don't want to display just counts.

If you need any more information please ask.

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 4):

```
select surveyid, staff, username, ipaddress
from table1
where ipaddress+staff in 
(
select ipaddress+staff
from table1
group by ipaddress,staff
having count(surveyid)>1
)
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68d1e/4)**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT surveyid,
        PT.staff,
        username,
        PT.ipaddress
   FROM PaulTable PT
        INNER JOIN 
        (
           SELECT ipaddress, staff
             FROM PaulTable
                  GROUP BY ipaddress, staff
                  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT username) > 1
        ) USECOUNT
            ON USECOUNT.ipaddress = PT.ipaddress
            AND USECOUNT.staff = PT.staff
```

Comment: Tried this as well but I get 0 results.

Comment: @PaulCreative    I didn't quite "get" what you were after:  I edited my response to provide you with what (I think) you're after, now.     There's a test instance at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30e1d/4